# Display only completed orders on my Woocommerce accounts page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the account area of my woocommerce shopping site you can click 'orders' and see your order i.e. completed, cancelled, on hold etc etc.

However when you click 'collection' (a page I have made within the account area) I want it to display only 'completed' items.

I have tried to put the following code into the functions.php but with no luck:

(ref - https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-products-purchased-user/)

```
add_shortcode( 'my_products', 'bbloomer_user_products_bought' );

function bbloomer_user_products_bought() {
global $product, $woocommerce, $woocommerce_loop;
$columns = 3;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_visibility',
            'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
            'compare'       => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

ob_start();

woocommerce_product_loop_start();
```

Loop part

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$theid = get_the_ID();
if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $theid ) ) {
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 
} 
endwhile; 

woocommerce_product_loop_end();

woocommerce_reset_loop();
wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

and then adding the shortcode:

```
[my_products]
```

when you click the collection link it does not display anything - well generates a div with nothing in it!

Is there a better way of doing this or a alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your $args with bellow code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'           => 'wc-completed'
);
```

Then let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response - I first replaced the whole '$args = array' section with what you provided with no result and then placed just the 'product' and 'publish' with 'shop_order' and 'wc-completed' but again it just produces the same '<div class="woocommerce columns-3"><ul class="products"> </ul></div>' with nothing in it.

Comment: Oh sorry there is a second part which I guess needs updating? I have added it to the question named 'loop part'